# With Pandoc, how to converting between different formats with additional rules?

Tags: pandoc

I have some existing Mediawiki format texts that contain categories tokens like

```
[[Category:XXX]]
[[Category:YYY]]
```

I'd like to convert them to Markdown texts.  The basic command for doing that with Pandoc is

```
pandoc -f mediawiki -t markdown -s mytext.mediawiki -o mytext.md
```

The resultant Markdown text is mostly usable except that it converts the category tokens to

```
<Category:XXX> <Category:YYY>
```

which isn't really what I need.  Instead, I need

```
[[!tag XXX YYY]]
```

because I'm using the resultant Markdown files as source files in a special content management system called Ikiwiki which has its idiosyncratic format for tags. How to do that with Pandoc?

Comment: it's probably easiest to do this as a second step with a search and replace on `<Category:XXX>`. note that pandoc without the `-o` option writes to standardout, so you can pipe it directly to some postprocessing step...

Comment: I guess I can accept this as a solution -- post processing Pandoc's outputs by my own scripts.  I was hoping the conversion rules for some content elements can be customized via Pandoc configuration and/or options.

Comment: Thanks, posted below with a cleaner alternative. btw, there are lots of [writer options](http://pandoc.org/README.html#options-affecting-specific-writers), but most are for the HTML, EPUB and LaTeX writers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to do this as a second step with a search and replace on `<Category:XXX>`. Note that pandoc without the `-o` option writes to standard-out, so you can pipe it directly to some custom post-processing script.

`[[Category:XXX]]` is converted by pandoc internally to a link along the lines of `<a href="Category:XXX" title="wikilink">Category:XXX</a>` (try `pandoc -f mediawiki -t native`).

So generally, additional rules for elements are implemented through custom scripts that match on [Pandoc's internal data types](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L189), see [**Pandoc scripting**](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html). So you could match on those kind of links. It's more work (the first time), but makes quite sure you don't replace false positives.